unsupported option '-G' for target 'arm64-apple-ios11.0-simulator'
This is my PodFile
platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
use_modular_headers!
prepare_react_native_project!

flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'Fixturefix' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()
 
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'react-native-config/Extension', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-config'

  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'FixturefixTests' do
    inherit! :complete
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if ['FirebaseCoreInternal', 'GoogleUtilities'].include?(target.name)
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['DEFINES_MODULE'] = 'YES'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

I am using a MacBook M1 with Sequoia 15.0
Xcode version 16.0
Then I am getting this error constantly when I am building on Xcode. I have no issue building and running a new project.
unsupported option '-G' for target 'arm64-apple-ios11.0-simulator'
Things I have tried.
rm -rf Podfile
rm -rf Podfile.lock
Pod install

Also tried 
pod deintegrate
pod install 

Double checked the iOS version of 16.0
I have lost several days on this please help,

I have the same problem , two days without any soluation

@AliAl-Amrad I have solved this by:
rebuilding a new project and then taking the iOS files out of there and replacing them in my current project. This is not an ideal solution but it has worked.

I have resolved using the same approach here: BoringSSL-GRPC unsupported option '-G' for target 'arm64-apple-ios15.0'
Pretty much just modify your podfile as:
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'react-native-config/Extension', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-config'

  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'FixturefixTests' do
    inherit! :complete
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      
      if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
        target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
          if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
            flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
            flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
            file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
          end
        end
      end
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
      end

      if ['FirebaseCoreInternal', 'GoogleUtilities'].include?(target.name)
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['DEFINES_MODULE'] = 'YES'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

Run pod upgrade clean build folder and build again.
I hope it helps!

I have resolved this issue by following the below steps:
Step 1 : Update cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods

pod repo update

Step 2 : delete the android and iOS folders from your app and run flutter create .
this is commad will create these 2 folders again (just to make sure we didn't make any changes on them).
Step 3 :  navigate your podfile ios/Podfile and past the code below
...
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
      target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
        if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
          flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
          flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
          file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
        end
      end
    end
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
    end
  end
end

...
Step 4 :  run the below command to open runnder file into xcode open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
Go to the target settings for your project.
Under the Build Settings tab, look for Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules and set it to Yes.

close xcode

Step 5 : open your code editor again and run flutter clean
flutter pub get 

flutter run 

Congratulations! Your code error solved
